# Thunderbird, how to select 1st tab programmatically?

Tags: javascript, mozilla, gecko

Select 1st tab programmatically?

?how to go to the 1st tab using code

I can move to 1st tab pressing Ctrl+1

?How can I do the same but with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Thunderbird's error console and try to enter this:

```
Components.classes['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1'].
    getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator).
    getMostRecentWindow("mail:3pane").
    document.getElementById("tabmail").
    switchToTab(0)
```

For more details about *tabmail* see its sources - it pretty well commented - https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mail/base/content/tabmail.xml